# Sometime Not Receiving push notification GCM in Mobile

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am facing a strange problem. I am getting push notification in my mobile, if it is connected to the internet at that point when message has been send from the server side. But if it is not connected to the internet at that time and rather I am connecting to internet after some time. I am not receiving that notification. According to my knowledge all those notifications should show whenever we are online, because GCM server stores all those messages. I am receiving notification for all other apps. Also I have given wakelock permission in manifest. What might be the problem? Anything from server side, client side or mobile? Please help...

**This value is send to GCM server from 3rd party server(.Net server):**

```
String postdata= "collapse_key=score_update&time_to_live=2419200&delay_while_idle=1&data.message=‌​" + 
message + "&data.time=" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + "&registration_id=" + deviceToken + ""
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 10):

`delay_while_idle=1` contradicts `Also I have given wakelock permission in manifest`

`delay_while_idle=1` means the message won't reach the device if it's idle (off, offline, locked screen, etc...). Change it to 0 if you want your wakelock permission to make any difference.

Just to clarify - the message should reach the device after it stops being idle (as long as it hadn't been idle for too long, where "too long" is determined by the specified `time_to_live`).

Here's the relevant quote from GCM documentation :

> **delay_while_idle**
>
> If included, indicates that the message should not be sent immediately
>   if the device is idle. The server will wait for the device to become
>   active, and then only the last message for each collapse_key value
>   will be sent. Optional. The default value is false, and must be a JSON
>   boolean.
>
> **time_to_live**
>
> How long (in seconds) the message should be kept on GCM storage if the
>   device is offline. Optional (default time-to-live is 4 weeks, and must
>   be set as a JSON number).

Comment: Are you sure. Because in documentation I found out that delay_while_idle flag should be true. So in the server side using .net server I am passing delay_while_idle=1(true), because 0(false). If you are confirmed then please let me know...

Comment: "delay while idle" means exactly what it says - delay the message delivery while the device is idle. When the device returns to be active (online, display is on), the message should be received. Wakelock permission is relevant if you want to wake the device and display the notification even when the device is locked. That's why it only makes sense to use it when `delay_while_idle=0`.

Comment: Thanks alot....Also is it required to append an incremental value to the collapse key value,i.e., score_update.

Comment: You're welcome. The value of `collapse key` depends on the content of the message. Messages that report the latest state of something, such as "Score is ...", should have the same collapse key, so that if you send two of those to the same device while it's idle, only the last one will be delivered when the device becomes active. Messages that contain different data, such as text sent from another user in a chat, should have different collapse key, so that all messages (up to a certain limit) that were stored by Google while the device was idle will be delivered when it's active again.

Comment: Now for example if I am sending two messages with different text within one hour. As per our knowledge if the device is active, We are getting both notifications in status bar. But if the device is idle when both messages are send, then will I receive both notifications with same collapse key or I have to append some incremental value.

Comment: If you want to recieve both notifications, you must use a different collapse key.

Comment: Finally then I am posting this data to GCM server from Server(.Net) end. Please confirm me: String i=i++;  String postdata= "collapse_key=i&time_to_live=2419200&delay_while_idle=0&data.message=‌​" + message + "&data.time=" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + "&registration_id=" + deviceToken + ""

Comment: Still not sure with the delay_while_idle flag. Because in http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html  clearly they have mention that delay_while_idle flag should be true. Thus delay_while_idle=0 is false, 1 is true. Though to recieve both notifications, different collapse key is required. Please reply...

Comment: Do you want the device to receive the message while it is idle, or do you want Google to postpone the delivery until the device gets active? If you want the former, use `delay_while_idle=0`, otherwise use `delay_while_idle=1`.

Comment: Now for an example take three devices. First device is always active and online, Second device is locked/asleep(but it is connected to internet), Third device is offline. Now if two notifications has been send from the server, first device will receive both notifications; second should receive both notifications whenever it becomes active; third device should receive both notifications whenever it is again online and also active. This is my requirement,now please tell me what should be the value of delay_while_idle and collapse_key???

Comment: @ARIJIT Can you share the answer if you've figured it out ?